# '@media' not working properly on css for responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

So, I'm recently trying to do responsive design with css. I'm going with mobile first approach. So after coding for mobile devices I coded for tablet devices and I targeted tablet devices with css media queries. My code looks like that,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  .content {
    background-image: url('../images/bgimage.jpg');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muYbL.png)
Since I don't have any tablet devices I tried to simulate it from my Chromium developers tool, Nexus 7 & Nexus 10 but as you can see in the below screenshot it isn't showing the background image as intended.
[browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHagt.png)
(Yes, I'm trying to clone Dropbox business)

I'm new to responsive design and don't know a lot things right now, I've searched as much as I can with my little knowledge but couldn't find any soulution, so here I'm.

Answer (score 0):

Its syntax-error You are missing a }.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 480px) {


.content {
    background-image: url('../images/bgimage.jpg');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, there are more codes for this query below the code I mentioned above, so that curly brace is at the end.

Comment: https://codepen.io/M4HD1BD/pen/xxKYxqN

Images are local so it won't appear

Comment: @Mahdi your media codea are running well, you forgot to remove large padding made on .one and .two classes in your media query. so those large paddings 150px i think are causing the problm

Comment: The thing is media queries are running properly, now its up to you, to adjust the font-sizes and paddings and spacing accordingly for those classes

Comment: I've just reseted padding for one & two class on my media query for tablet but still nothing changed

Comment: You have not reseted padding, I think you should try inspecting the screen , find what value of padding is currently being used and from which rule is the value coming and change accordingly,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your code without media query. But you can use it in following way.

```css
.background {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  
  background-color: #fcc600;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) and (min-width: 400px) {
  .background {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="background">ABCD</div>
```

See the `background-color` changes when you go beyond 980px and less than 400px.

Check screenshots for your codepen.

[image: Greater than 960px]

[image: Less than 960px]

Comment: https://codepen.io/M4HD1BD/pen/xxKYxqN

take a look at full code, I coded for mobile devices first.

Comment: On codepen you don't have access to `../images/bgimage.jpg`. Try changing it to `background-color` it works. I just tried.

Comment: can you check the code presuming they are here? i can up those images somewhere and edit in the code if you want

Comment: Check the screenshots added above. I just added `background-color` instead of image for `.content` class in media query. Please check the resolution in screenshot.

Comment: So, I've exactly copied your code but first I changed max-width to 960px and min-width to 480px and guess what  background color remained yellow when I set width in between 480px and 960. Then I changed it to what you gave, 980px and 400 and now background color remained Red whether it is less than 400 or greater than 400

Comment: I am not sure, what you are trying exactly. If you look at the screenshot (Codepen), I just replaced `background-color` property in your existing code. And it works fine. It also works fine in code snippet I've added.